# Listar dados json em <ul> <li>

Tags: javascript, json

Gente, tenho um sisteminha aqui que ele pega os dados em um JSON e lista em uma página HTML, porém ele está com a lista da seguinte forma: ele exibe apenas um título e a cada vez que eu atualizo meu navegador ele exibe o próximo título.

Gostaria que ele fosse um em baixo do outro. Exibir todos os título em `ul li`.

O código que acredito que listaria seria esse abaixo:

```js
var cemf = cemf || {
  js: {}
};

cemf.js.Interface = function(lista){};

cemf.js.Interface.prototype.GerarItem = function(lista){

    $(' #Titulo') 
     $('#Titulo').html(lista.Titulo);

};
```

Exemplo do JSON que é passado:

```js
[{"Object":"foto1","Titulo":"Exemplo do titulo 1"},{"Object":"foto2.jpg","Titulo":"Titulo":"Exemplo do titulo 2"}]
```

Comment: Tem como você mostrar  um exemplo do json que você usa?

Comment: Favor postar o modelo JSON.

Comment: Você quer percorrer o json, com um loop?

Comment: Editei a sua pergunta para colocar nela o JSON. Para manter as coisas organizadas, por favor, mantenha na pergunta tudo que faz parte da pergunta e mantenha nas respostas apenas aquilo que busca responder a pergunta feita.

Comment: Leo Letto 6 isso mesmo percorrer um loop

Comment: @ Leo Letto isson mesmo meu diretor isso que eu gostaria de fazer loop

Comment: Resolveu sua duvida?